# spring openid +remember me

Tags: java, spring, gwt, openid, spring-security

```
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    super.afterPropertiesSet();

    if (consumer == null) {
        try {
            consumer = new OpenID4JavaConsumer();
        } catch (ConsumerException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to initialize OpenID", e);
        }
    }

    if (returnToUrlParameters.isEmpty() &&
            getRememberMeServices() instanceof AbstractRememberMeServices) {
        returnToUrlParameters = new HashSet<String>();
        returnToUrlParameters.add(((AbstractRememberMeServices)getRememberMeServices()).getParameter());
    }
}
```

Inside Spring OpenIDAuthenticationFilter, i can see above, what is the use of 
`returnToUrlParameters.add(((AbstractRememberMeServices)getRememberMeServices()).getParameter());`  ?

what does rememberMeService relate to returnto-page after doing openid?

Answer (score 0):

You may read this article written by Peter Mularien the author of spring security 
http://www.packtpub.com/article/opening-up-to-openid-with-spring-security

quote " You'll note that we don't offer the remember me option with OpenID login. This is due to the fact that the redirection to and from the vendor causes the remember me checkbox value to be lost, such that when the user's successfully authenticated, they no longer have the remember me option indicated. This is unfortunate, but ultimately increases the security of OpenID as a login mechanism for our site, as OpenID forces the user to establish a trust relationship through the provider with each and every login. "